# How to increase the maximum size of a cookie?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I know the maximum size of a cookie is 4kb but I need to store some more data in a single cookie. is there any way to do it in PHP, Laravel.

Comment: Use another cookie? Use localstorage?

Comment: Good question... Can you tell what are you going to achieve, what problem do you want to solve with it?

Comment: As I am storing my cart in the cookie, it will be hard for me to use another cookie. I am thinking about using LocalStorage. is there any way to use LocalStorage with PHP instead of js?

Comment: You could pack the values to binary somehow and send them base64_encoded maybe. This could give you a bit more room which could be a solution if that's all you need. Obviously, they would need to be decoded and unpacked on the client side.

Answer (score 4):

In a modern browser you have better client-side storage alternatives. It is not a good idea to add an overhead of more than 4KB to every HTTP request.

You can have a maximum of 50 cookies per domain and a total of 4KB. i.e. you can have 1 cookie of 4096 bytes, or 2 cookies with 2048, and so on.

You could try using sessions, but I would recommend looking into [HTML5 localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) that allows you to store larger amounts of data instead of passing them back and forth using cookies.

Comment: is there any way to access HTML5 localStorage with php instead of js?

Comment: @SeamHoque LocalStorage is client  side and PHP is server side. So you cannot directly get access to LocalStorage using PHP. However it can easily be accomplished by sending LocalStorage values to your server via AJAX and then you have the values on your server in PHP.